# Удаление нулей в Java

Tags: java, jsp

вывожу в таблицу на странице jsp переменную `<td><c:out value="${vp44150sql.kol}" /></td>`, нужно удалить не значащие нули, есть число например такое 1.00000000, тут нужно удалить все 8 нулей, а есть и такое 0.02500000 - тут нужно удалить только последние 5, кто знает как это сделать? Может это можно как-то в самом sql запросе сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSTL включает [средства для форматирования](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html):

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="0.02500000" type="number"/>
```

Comment: так тоже работает, но есть вопрос, можно ли такую конструкцию применить  к такому коду `<td><%=pList.get(4)%></td>`?

Comment: работает и в таком виде `<td><fmt:formatNumber value="<%=pList.get(5)%>" type="number"/></td>` , и этот вариант даже больше подходит, так как данные экспортируются в ексель

Comment: Можно так `<fmt:formatNumber value="${ pList.get(4) }" type="number"/>`, а скриптлеты лучше не использовать.

Comment: когда так  `"${ pList.get(4) }"` то данные почему-то в таблице не видны

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если эти данные представлены строкой, то поможет следующая замена:

```
s.replaceAll("\\.(.*?)0+$", ".$1").replaceAll("\\.$", "");
```

Ну а в случае, если это не строка - привести к строке и заменить аналогично.

Здесь сначала удаляются нули с конца строки, если они идут после точки, а затем удаляется точка, если после неё ничего не осталось.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь)